# getText from one layout and (setting it) setText in an other layout

Tags: android-layout, gettext, settext

i call this method SolveUpdation (from button- onclickAction Listener) from mainAcitivity with main layout. i use other layout to get value from user and set it as button title in the main layout and that is only instruction that does not works for me

```
    private void  SolveUpdation() {     //this function call is generated from the main Activity with main layout       
        setContentView(R.layout.updateappliance); //this is 2nd layout to get values from user and use them as buttonText in the main layout   

        btnSaveApp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Bupdatenow);
        btnSaveApp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {       
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  mOutEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_1);               
                  TextView view1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_1);
                  final String TitleApp1 = view1.getText().toString();  //the value is read properly here

//                if (App1.length() > 0) {
//                    byte[] send = App1.getBytes();
//                }

                btnSaveApp.setText(TitleApp1); //this works fine
                startActivity(new Intent(HomeScreen.this, HomeScreen.class));//this the main activity for main layout
                setContentView(R.layout.main); //this is the main layout and this instruction works
                buttonLED1.setText(TitleApp1); //buttonLED1 (a Togglebutton or can be simple) is  defined in main layout and this does not works and this is what i am stuck with
                SaveAppNamesToast(TitleApp1);   //this is just to toast the value and it works fine.
            }});
```

So plz can any one guide me why this instruction buttonLED1.setText(TitleApp1); does not works ??? Any help will be appreciatable.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No offense, but the way you write your code is not a good practice. 
My advise: Stop calling another `setContentView` in your Main Activity. You should rather implement all needed Buttons and EditTexts in one layout and set their visiblity to `gone` or `visible` depending on which button was clicked.

If you don't wanna do this you should create a second class that handles the input of the user. After pressing the save button you initialize your intent for the main activity and give it via `intent.putExtra("KEY", value)` the input of the user.
Your Main Activity can receive this value via `getIntent().getExtras().getInt("KEY")`.

By the way: I think your current code doesn't work because of the new Activity you start. Through this everything gets initialized again so the `buttonLED1` that you see isn't the same `buttonLED1` that gets the text.

Comment: i guess the way you told is some what i thought of, but i had not knowledge of these specific keyterms as i am beginner.. let me try this... You great... thanks dude..